# Using Suffix in Elastic NEST 2.0

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to create a multi_field for one of my properties to get the raw value using a suffix

```
elasticClient.CreateIndex(IndexName.From<ResultModel>(),
    index => index.Mappings(
        mappings => mappings.Map<ResultModel>(
            map => map.AutoMap().Properties(
                properties => properties.String(
                    s => s.Name(e => e.Name.Suffix("raw")).Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

However looking at the index that gets created it is being named `raw`, no prefix of the field name.

[image: field name]

Documentation is a little sketchy for NEST 2.0 and the only documentation I can find is their test case scenarios when serializing the output:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html

Anyone has any idea on how to create these multi_fields with suffix in NEST 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1707#issuecomment-170590859) and [that](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1708) issues from NEST github explain how you can do this with version 2.

In your case that's going to be something like:

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(IndexName.From<ResultModel>(),
    index => index.Mappings(
        mappings => mappings.Map<ResultModel>(
            map => map.AutoMap().Properties(
                properties => properties.String(
                    s => s.Name(e => e.Name)
                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)
                        .Fields(f => f.String(s2 => s2.Name("raw").Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also check out the example at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html#attribute-mapping, just after the section starting "_Just as we were able to override the inferred properties in our earlier example,_"